# Restricted representations and irreducibility (in $SL_2(q)$)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm working through the Fulton-Harris ad-hoc method of constructing the character table of $SL_2(q)$ (for $q$ an odd prime power), $\S$5.2 for reference.

I am at a point where we are considering representations of $GL_2(q)$, and how they decompose on restriction to a subgroup of index 2 (specifically the subgroup of elements with square determinant, which we will call $H$). We then consider the further restriction from this subgroup to $SL_2(q)$.

I understand almost everything. There are two irreducible representations of $GL_2(q)$, say $W,X$, that each split into a direct sum of irreducible representations of $H$: $\ \ W|_{H}=W'\oplus W''$, $X|_H = X'\oplus X''$. We know the dimensions of these representations - each is half the dimension of the larger rep.

Now, we have classified all irreducible representations of $SL_2(q)$ except 4, whose dimensions are known to be the same as $W',W'',X',X''$. The book then claims (bottom of page 72):

"This shows that these representations ($W',W'',X',X''$) stay irreducible on restriction from $H$ to $SL_2(q)$."

I'm confused as to why they make this assumption - or am I overlooking something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider well ordered sets, pairs and triples, in the context of vectors. The representations will then be seen a the monads of the field, i.e no other algebraic law will reach those sets.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of monads so I'm little confused by what you mean here? could you clarify a bit? thanks!

Comment: Now posted on MathOverflow: [Assumption in Fulton & Harris? (representations of $SL_2(q)$)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/279207). I think that [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) contains a very reasonable advice about cross-posting. (Of course, other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting] might be of interest, too.)